# Reoccurring Python syntax error in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

The lines below are all the code I have on my terminal so I don't think it's the missing parenthesis. Plus the print() is not on line 6 as well so I'm super confused. I am using Python 3.

This is the code that ran into syntax error:

```
import re
fhand = open("regex_sum_42.txt")

sum = 0
for line in fhand:
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for word in x:
        sum = sum + int(word)
        
print(sum)
```

And this is the error message returned:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    print(sum)
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong here? I am very new to Python and just started to use terminal to run my Python code. Is there something wrong with the command on my terminal?

```
Last login: Fri Apr 21 13:21:03 on ttys001

evonneni@Evonnes-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd desktop

evonneni@Evonnes-MacBook-Pro desktop % cd py4e

evonneni@Evonnes-MacBook-Pro py4e % pwd

/Users/evonneni/desktop/py4e

evonneni@Evonnes-MacBook-Pro py4e % python3

Python 3.11.2 (v3.11.2:878ead1ac1, Feb  7 2023, 10:02:41) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python 3.x make print work like in Python 2 (as statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896749/in-python-3-x-make-print-work-like-in-python-2-as-statement)

Comment: The code you show does not produce that error message (in particular, the `print` call is not on line 6). Please provide a reproducible example. Also, you are probably missing a closing parenthesis somewhere before the error.

Comment: If you're new to Python you should not be using 2.7. It has been EOL for years.

Comment: @ti7 Isn't this the opposite of that question?

Comment: @ti7 `print(x)` is fine both in Python 2 and Python 3. The SyntaxError here is most probably coming from some problem in a previous line (unmatched brackets, missing colon etc)

Comment: Random syntax errors like this are 99% due to missing `)` on the previous line.

Comment: The lines above are all the code I have on my terminal so I don't think there's anything wrong with the parenthesis. Plus the print() is not on line 6 as well so I'm super confused

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: I just pasted my code from brackets to terminal

Comment: What if instead you tried `python3 your_file_name.py`? What happens then?

Comment: Does it matter if my file is .txt file and not .py?

Comment: Note `sum` is a rather important python function and this code clobbers it.

Comment: The problem is probably actually caused by having a blank line that shouldn't be there, before `sum = 0`. Try removing that blank line. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391633/blank-line-rule-at-interactive-prompt

Comment: This is interesting. If I copy-paste the code into an interactive Python interpreter, I *do* in fact get a syntax error on the `print` call. The reason seems to be that there is some whitespace on the line above, which apparently confuses the parser, but I'll have to leave it to someone else to figure out why — it does not happen when the code is in a file. There's probably something special about how Python detects the end of a block in interactive mode. Anyway, clear out the spaces from the line before the `print` and it works.

Comment: @TurePålsson From the question I linked to, it looks like when you paste into the interpreter, blank lines are mandatory at the end of loops but forbidden elsewhere

Comment: @slothrop - The key being *interactive interpreter*.  Yes.  If run as a script, no blank lines are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found out how to reproduce the error. So you can solve your problem. But I don't know why it is an error.

If you have an indented blank line or no line before your print it would fail.

So removing it would resolve the problem:

```
import re
fhand = open("regex_sum_42.txt")

sum = 0
for line in fhand:
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for word in x:
        sum = sum + int(word)
        # <- Empty this line
print(sum)
```

So your code would look like this:

```
import re
fhand = open("regex_sum_42.txt")

sum = 0
for line in fhand:
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for word in x:
        sum = sum + int(word)

#^ this line is empty
print(sum)
```

Please notice the code below would fail too:

```
import re
fhand = open("regex_sum_42.txt")

sum = 0
for line in fhand:
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for word in x:
        sum = sum + int(word)
print(sum)
```

### Notice

I tested it on Windows (conda), Linux (wsl) and PopOS (conda).

The error line does not have to be a `print` line. Any line would fail.

I wrote a simple script for the test and it failed too. So it's nothing to do with your code. **You need a blank, unintended line between your indented and unintended lines**.

test script:

```
x = 0
for i in range(22):
    x += i
    
print(x)
```

fails too...

### Confusion

The same error does not occur when the code returns to a lower indentation from a multi-indented line.

For example, after seeing we need a blank line after indentation I expected the codes below both fail before `x += i`.

code 1:

```
x = 0
for i in range(22):
    if x==1:
        print("ONE")
        # <- There is a line
    x += i

print(x)
```

code 2:

```
x = 0
for i in range(22):
    if x==1:
        print("ONE")
    x += i

print(x)
```

But they do not. The interpreter clearly understands that the if block is ended and parse the code.

### TL;DR

Have a blank, unintended line between your last indented line and print.

Comment: I have never heard of (nor read about) the need for a blank line for a function to work.  In fact, we have as a coding standard that there are no blank lines within methods or functions. I’m afraid this is a red herring; or a system- specific issue.  Not a Python requirement.  (Unless you can produce Python documentation stating otherwise.)

Comment: @S3DEV I just checked the codes above on a `gnome-terminal` to be sure it is not something about `cmd`. Unfortunately, it fails as I described. And as I said, I don't know why it happening, but I can reproduce the error...

Comment: THANK YOU! This method solved my problem, yet I am still very confused about why I need to do this as I've never read about having to leave a blank line before my function. If anyone could elaborate on what could possibly caused this issue would be very helpful!

Comment: *** This is the key: To clarify, if running this statement-by-statement in an *interactive interpreter*; yes - a blank line is required after the for loop, *due to interpreter parsing*.    If run as a script; or otherwise a program - a blank is not required.

Comment: @S3DEV I totally understand that the interpreter needs to understand if an indentation is ended or not. So a blank line is required. What I don't get is why we need a blank line when an unintended new line is produced. This problem does not occur when you return to a lower indentation, from multiple indented line...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like python 2 version is being used. In this case syntax should be as in python 2 print is a statement not function.

```
print sum
```

Comment: In Python 2, **both** `print sum` and `print(sum)` are valid

Comment: I am using python 3. Not sure why this error keeps appearing...

Comment: Could this be because sum is built in? Can you try using variable as Sum?

Comment: I tried using Sum instead but the same error message occured

Comment: i think i understood the issue. Since you are running this from terminal,  terminal needs a line of space to know that the for loop has ended. Therefore, try typing the code into the terminal (dont copy) and give a blank line after sum=sum+int(word) and then print.  Alternatively run code as mentioned by marcelo above: python3 your_file_name.py

Comment: Blank lines are a good call - but it looks like there is already a blank line after the `for` loop. The problem is probably actually caused by having a blank line that **shouldn't** be there, before `sum = 0`. Try removing that blank line.

Comment: This error message occur when I tried to do python3 your_file_name.py:
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 134)